# Confusion about notation in Fourier Series Definition 8.10 , Rudin

Tags: real-analysis

I have a question about the notation of Fourier series in the book. The sum begins from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ in equation (63), but the sum begins from $1$ in equation (67). I think **definition 8.10** generalizes the form of Fourier series, but if we plug in $\frac{1}{\sqrt {2\pi}}$$e^{inx}$, we should get equation (63), but it doesn't begin from -$\infty$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indices $n$ in these two equations are not the same. For trigonometric functions, it's convenient to label them by the frequency and thus let the index run from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. In the general case, it's more convenient to label the general functions with natural numbers. To apply that to the trigonometric Fourier series, you'd have to relabel the functions, e.g. as

\begin{eqnarray*}
\phi_{2n-1}&=&\mathrm e^{\mathrm i(n-1)x}\;,\\
\phi_{2n}&=&\mathrm e^{-\mathrm inx}\;.
\end{eqnarray*}